# is it possible to implement quicksort in loco with a list?

Tags: java, list, quicksort

I implemented quickSort algorithm in java in a static way using arrays.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void quickSort(T[] A){
    quickSort(A, 0, A.length-1);
}

private static <T extends Comparable<T>> void quickSort(T[] A, int p, int r){
    if(p < r){
        int q = partition(A, p, r);
        quickSort(A, p, q);
        quickSort(A, q+1, r);
    }
}

private static <T extends Comparable<T>> int partition(T[] A, int p, int r){
    T x = A[p];
    int i = p;
    int j = r;
    while(true){
        while(A[j].compareTo(x) > 0 && j > p){
            j--;
        }
        while(A[i].compareTo(x) < 0 && i < r){
            i++;
        }
        if(i < j)
            swap(A, i, j);
        else
            return j;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to implement this algorithm using Lists, preserving "in loco" property. I thought that it's a problem to use a list without index, because you need to know after the two different "while"  , if the reference belongs to a node that is before another one. Does anyone know a way to avoid this trouble?

Comment: @khelwood It does not, QuickSort is only used to sort primitive arrays. Others use MergeSort (earlier versions)/TimSort (as of Java 7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with implementing this same algorithm using a List rather than an array. You can use a List just like an array: using `set` and `get` methods. It also has convenient methods such as `subList` that are useful for quicksort. A sublist is a view of the list; no copying is involved. So this removes the need to pass the upper and lower limits.

```
static void sort(List<Integer> list) {
    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
        int pivotValue = list.get(list.size() - 1);
        int storeIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
            if (list.get(i) < pivotValue) {
                Collections.swap(list, i, storeIndex++);
            }
        }
        Collections.swap(list, list.size() - 1, storeIndex);
        sort(list.subList(0, storeIndex));
        sort(list.subList(storeIndex + 1, list.size()));
    }
}
```

You refer to an issue with using Lists without indexes. It is, of course, possible to `add` and `remove` objects from a list without ever using an index. However it's hard to see how you could implement quicksort without ever using an index. For example picking pivots and swapping elements all require indexing.